# How can I modify the xlist environment of gb4e to allow for alphabetical numbering beyond "z"?

Tags: numbering, linguistics, examples, gb4e

I am using the *gb4e* package to typeset my (rather numerous) examples.
I am trying to modify the *xlist* (or *xlista*) environment of said package to allow for alphabetically numbered sub-examples beyond z, such as aa, ab, ac, and so on. The default environment only allows numbering up to z, after which the error "Counter too large" pops up and the numbering gets replaced by a period.

I have tried using the *alphalph* package, but I am unsure of how to modify the environment and which commands to use. I've made several attempts with no luck.

See my (somewhat) minimal WE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}\noautomath

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
    \ex test
    \ex \begin{xlist}
        \ex ok
        \ex ok 
        \ex ok
        \ex ok
        \ex ok
        \ex ok
        \ex ok
        \ex ok
        \ex ok
        \ex ok 
        \ex ok
        \ex ok
        \ex ok
        \ex ok
        \ex ok
        \ex ok
        \ex ok
        \ex ok 
        \ex ok
        \ex ok
        \ex ok
        \ex ok
        \ex ok
        \ex ok
        \ex ok
        \ex ok 
        \ex not ok
    \end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

How can I modify the *xlist* (or *xlista*) environment to allow for alphabetically numbered sub-examples beyond z?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for adding a sample document with your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `alphalph` package, and modify the `xnumii` counter. What maybe threw you off in your tests is that to use the `\alphalph` macro with a counter, you need to use the `\value` of the counter; you can't just use `\alphalph{<counter>}` like you would with `\alph`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\renewcommand\thexnumii{\alphalph{\value{xnumii}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex A long list
\begin{xlist}
\setcounter{xnumii}{24} % for example code only
\ex An example
\ex An example
\ex An example
\ex An example
\ex An example
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]